# linux raid5 with 7 disks have readerror without readerror of one of the drives

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

i have a mysterious problem: i install a raid5 array with 7 1,5 TB disks in one of my server for some years under kernel 2.6.x with metadata 0.9 and have no problems.

in the last weeks, i update this server to a new system with actual kernel an reinit the raid with metadata 1.2. after this, i restore all data from backup und verify them. i am a little paranoid in such things, since i have some data lost while memory, disk or scsi-bus produce corrupt data.
the verify failed for one file. so i check the whole raid and find one position with a read error. i change the raid to the old format with the old system and test it again. no error.
i make a restart with the new kernel and check it again: no error.

at the moment i make an integrity check of the whole raid (need 150 Hours or so).

but why have my raid5 a readerror, if i use metadata 1.2 (kernel 5.4.66) and no error with metadata 0.9.

i use the hole drive the the raid without partion and it was 7 disks of the same type.

this drives me crazy!

goodby

Comment: What does SMART say for the disks? Has there been a read error reported by the kernel?

Comment: smart says that the disks are ok and the kernel don't report any readerror. absolutly no message at the moment the readerror occurs.